# Fail to whitelist node pattern for neo4j-stream with kafka

Tags: database, neo4j, apache-kafka, stream, nosql

I've configured neo4j-stream support to auto-publish notification to kafka from neo4j. Using neo4j-3.4.11 Enterprise Edition

Since I've large number of nodes which I don't want to be considered for Kafka notification, I've used producer pattern to whitelist only the nodes I want to publish. Let's consider I want to just publish Car and Bike node.

I refer https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/neo4j-streams/current/producer/#producer-patterns for the configuration and PFB the configuration we followed for this usecase:

```
kafka.zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
kafka.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
kafka.num.partitions=1
kafka.retries=2
kafka.batch.size=16384
kafka.buffer.memory=33554432
kafka.reindex.batch.size=1000
kafka.session.timeout.ms=15000
kafka.connection.timeout.ms=2000
kafka.replication=1
kafka.linger.ms=1

streams.source.topic.nodes.neo4j_nodes=CAR{*};BIKE{*};
#streams.source.topic.relationships.neo4j_relationships=*
streams.source.schema.polling.interval=10000
streams.source.enable=true
```

However, neo4j is still sending all other nodes data despite this pattern config.

Is there any additional setting s that needs to be done?

Comment: What version of the Streams plugin are you using?

Comment: its for neo version 3.4.11

Comment: Yes but there are multiple versions of the plug-in that are compatible with that version of Neo - what's the file name?

Answer (score 0):

With the most recent versions of the Neo4j Streams plugin, the syntax for filtering nodes [uses curly braces, and not parentheses](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/neo4j-streams/current/producer/#_nodes) - I can't find a version that's used parentheses before, and trying to use your configuration on the latest version just crashes out Neo as it starts up so it's unclear how you're getting a running instance. I'm wondering if older versions silently ignored the configuration parameter if it was invalid.

Regardless at the very least I'd suggest changing your configuration to be:

```
streams.source.topic.nodes.neo4j_nodes=CAR{*};BIKE{*};
```

and retry.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion....I used '{}' actually....a stupid typo here :(

Comment: In fact I tried with 'streams.source.topic.nodes.neo4j_nodes=CAR;BIKE;' as well but no luck

Comment: What version of the plug-in are you using then? I tried with the latest version against Neo 3.4.11 and it seems to work as expected so I'm wondering what the difference could be

Comment: Filtering is working for you? Are you getting other nodes data from kafka apart from Car and Bike nodes?